# Several items for one construct

Tags: correlation, survey, excel, psychometrics, descriptive-statistics

I am a dummy in statistics but need to accomplish some simple survey analyses.
My question is: if I have several questions (items) for one construct (say, questions JS1-JS3 for job satisfaction) with the same 5-point scale, how do I do descriptive stats for the construct?

Is it ok to calculate the mean & standard deviation across all
questions for the items? (imagine I have 20 respondents, then the
table of answers is 20 x 3 columns of questions JS1-JS3 - do I select
the whole area for excel functions?)
Do I use Std Deviation or Std Deviation for population function in excel?

How do I get cronbach alpha for this set?

Also, if I have several constructs within the survey that are measured with multiple items, how do I perform correlations analysis?

Please, help! Thanks a lot, experts!

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick! You are right in everything you said. The thing is, the study was not developed by me, so I don't need to dive that deep, I just need to perform some analysis. Although your information is helpful!

Comment: Hence, I know which items refer to which constructs. But I'd like to evaluate reliability - with Cronbach alpha, as you said.

Comment: OK.  I'd still recommend doing some general reading about psychometrics so that you know what is often done in your situation and what is possible to do.  After all, doing some analyses will not be useful if you don't know the sorts of issues that are important in these situations!  Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: I guess I should @PatrickS.Forscher! *embarrassed*  Could you recommend any readings please (if you have them on top of your head)?

Comment: There's a very nice introduction by William Revelle over at the Personality Project https://personality-project.org/r/book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to read up a bit about [psychometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometrics).  Therefore, I'm going to address the conceptual issues behind your question rather than how to accomplish specific tasks in Excel.

If you have no idea a priori how many clusters are in your set of items, the general procedure in psychometrics is to do an [exploratory factor analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis).  The first step of an exploratory factor analysis is a [principle components analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_components_analysis), which tells you how many factors are likely in your set of items, after which one generally does what is called a factor rotation, which tells you which items correspond to which factors.  By examining the items that tend to cluster together, you can interpret what each cluster of items is measuring.  While there are some general guidelines for how to conduct an exploratory factor analysis, the process is as much an art as a science -- there are no goodness of fit tests for whether your EFA was "successful".

If you have an idea a priori of how many clusters are in your set of items (and which items are in which clusters), the general procedure in psychometrics is to do a [confirmatory factor analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmatory_factor_analysis).  Confirmatory factor analysis tests whether a given measurement model has good fit to a set of data.

Once you have some idea of which items correspond to which constructs, it is generally acceptable to take the average of those items and treat that average as one variable.  However, you should still assess the [reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28psychometrics%29) and [validity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_%28statistics%29) of your instrument before diving into other analyses.

Reliability refers to whether, if you measure something multiple times with the same instrument, those measurements will produce similar results.  In the context of a multi-item scale, reliability is often measured using [Cronbach's alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha), which measures the extent to which the items on a scale "hang together" or cohere.

Validity, on the other hand, refers to whether a given instrument actually measures the thing that it is intended to measure.  Some ways to assess the validity of an instrument are through obtaining sets of correlations to determine whether your measure is positively related to the constructs that it should, logically, be related to, and whether your measure is unrelated to the constructs that it should, logically, be unrelated to.  This is often accomplished by constructing a [multi-trait multi-method matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitrait-multimethod_matrix).

Really, psychometrics is a big field of study, so I recommend doing some reading so that you know what's possible (and what makes sense in the context of your data) before diving in head-first.

Comment: nice answer @Patrick_S._Forscher. It is very hard not to just throw your hands in the air and query where one should begin.  You did well to provide some interesting guidance without bogging down too much in detail.

Comment: I agree with @doug.numbers and am very grateful to Patrick!